# My paper was under awaiting reviewer assignment then awaiting ed final processing. What does this indicate?

Tags: journals

I have submitted a research paper in Elsevier journal. After 18 days the status was "Awaiting Reviewer Assignment". And after 4 months the status changed to "awaiting EIC decision". And now statues is "awaiting ed final processing". Can anybody please tell me what does it indicate?

Comment: @scaaahu It seems that in the current case, the paper did not go under the normal review process.  I could not guess what this possibly means.

Comment: @PsySp There is a section "Editorial decision" in the answer of the linked question.

Comment: @scaaahu Yes. But this is a follow-up step of the review process. From the OP's comment, it is not obvious that reviewers assessed the paper. At least not _all_ invited reviewers. Also notice that two different things: It is one things "awaiting _Editor's_ decision" and another "EiC" decision.

Comment: @PsySp I think you're right. "Under Review" is missing before "awaiting EIC decision". I missed it when I read the question. Thanks. I retracted my close vote and deleted the dup message. Hopefully someone can come up with a reasonable explanation. Thanks again.

Comment: @scaaahu My only guess is that the Editor invited some reviewers, not all of which accepted. This caused the system to stuck in "Awaiting reviewer Assignment". Then, the other reviewers submitted their reviews and the Editor decided to go with these reviews only. So, now it's in the normal process of the Editor assessing the reviews. If this makes sense, Ic an post it as an answer.